# IMacros extract text from one file to another file

Tags: javascript, imacros

**Copy text one file to another using imacros**

```
> SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

> SET !DATASOURCE fire2.txt SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

> SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=runer.bat
```

Comment: What do you need help with? What does this have to do with Windows batch files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workarounds I would advise:

```
SET myFolder {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=file:///{{myFolder}}/fire2.txt
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET newText EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');")
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.write("{{newText}}");document.close();}
WAIT SECONDS=1
SAVEAS TYPE=TXT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=runer.bat
TAB CLOSE
```